# How to trigger a tap event on Chrome devtool console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

How can I use the Chrome-devtool's console to test if my javascript works? I've located the xpath and converted it to an css locator. Basically it is a button that turns the color from grey to blye.

Here is my snippet code:
browser.execute_script("$('button.nominate').trigger('tap');")

On the console, I tried something like:

> $('button.nominate').trigger('tap')

The result shown below:

> []

I thought it would tap the button

Comment: if you type `console.log($('button.nominate').length)` would it then output `0`. Think your selector (css locator :) ) is wrong.

Comment: Null and @Konrad Dzwinel thanks for your help. Apparently, I did use the wrong css selector. I also found out that converting an XPATH to CSS might not yield good results. I was told that my CSS was too specific and I should rely on using the class names to do it. I used http://cssify.appspot.com/ to help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose you are doing some kind of functional testing on your mobile app. I was doing the same thing some time ago (using CasperJS) and, in the process, I've created this function:

```
// I've commented out CasperJS specific stuff, don't use it if you don't need it
function triggerEventOnPage(selector, eventName, memo) {
    //casper.evaluate(function(selector, eventName, memo){
        var event;
        var element = document.querySelector(selector);

        event = document.createEvent("Event");
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        event.memo = memo || { };

        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    //}, selector, eventName, memo);
    //wait();
}
```

You can use it in your tests by calling:

```
triggerEventOnPage(".edit-list-button", 'tap');
```

However, mind that there is no native `tap` event. There are only `touchstart`, `tachmove`, `touchend` events and implementation of `tap` is done based on those three. Therefore, implementation of `tap` event that you are using may differ from one that I was using and the function above may not work for you.

**EDIT:** since you are using jQuery, `$('button.nominate').trigger('tap')` should work just fine to. @NULL may be right that your selector is invalid.

Comment: Brilliant!! Worked great for me!!