# Trigger an event from chrome developer studio

Tags: java, rest, server

I want to trigger an event directly from the Chrome developer tools.
I know that I can inspect an element and than reference to it using `$0` [in the console](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/chrome-developer-tools-monitorevents).

But how can I trigger a dom-event, on this element?

Comment: Is there an option I can do it directly from the Chrome developer tools UI directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. As a matter of fact you can try it right here on Stackoverflow.
Inspect your inbox. You will trigger a click event on that element.
Stackoverflow is convenient since it has jQuery already loaded so you can just do

```
$($0).trigger( "click");
```

And you will see the inbox behave as you would expect (open). 
The command above uses jQuery `$()` to wrap the element `$0` you have available.
With this you have all the beautiful functionality of jQuery.

In general you can use vanilla javascript for this too, but the commands for triggering events depend on the browser you are using.

You can of course load jQuery yourself via the command line 
just copy the content of [this](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js) paste it in the command line and press enter.
This will work great if the page you are viewing doesn't do anything that would cause any conflicts.

Moreover you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823530/how-to-trigger-a-tap-event-on-chrome-devtool-console) for vanilla javascript.

Comment: In my case I don't have jQuery in the html.
Can I add it dynamically?

Comment: Can I trigger events from the UI directly? Without using the console

Comment: I describe the method to include jquery via the command line, in my answer. I don't understand your second question.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you're using chrome, you can use the URL-bar to simply type

> javascript:document.getElementById("submit-button").form.submit()

to, in this case, submit an answer to StackOverflow. This way you can also trigger any other event, for example a url-click:

> javascript:document.getElementById("answer-33569491").children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[1].click()

This can also be entered in a watch, then you can execute it multiple times.